# Wordpress; Change position of post type in dashboard menu

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child, custom-post-type

I would like to change the position of a custom post type which was created by our parent theme.

I see I can change the position of a custom post type which we have created in our functions.php file by passing the arguments:

```
'menu_position'      => 5,
```

How can you do this for a post type created by the parent theme?

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of manipulating the global variable `$menu`. Add the following to the child theme `functions.php` and adjust the position and the title of your CPT menu item:

```
# Lambda function, requires PHP 5.3+
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    global $menu;
    $new_position = 1;
    $cpt_title = 'Slides';
    # Debug
    //printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $menu, true ) ); die();
    foreach( $menu as $key => $value )
    {
        if( $cpt_title === $value[0] )
        {
            $copy = $menu[$key];
            unset( $menu[$key] );
            $menu[$new_position] = $copy;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is helpful but it can overwrite an existing menu item.